# login don't work in django user not login

Tags: django, django-login

login dont work i don't where the problem please help.

https://youtu.be/tUqUdu0Sjyc ----- Dennis Ivy -- video learn in youtube

views

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'post':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="username" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

url

```
path('login/', views.login, name="login")
```

Comment: The request method is uppercase - `if request.method == 'POST':`

Comment: Please explain what is not working. Do you get an error? If yes, please post full traceback.

Comment: Don't name the view `login`...

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

- the `request.method` is *always* in uppercase; and
- you have a name clash between the view function, and the function of `auth`.

You thus check this with:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login as login_auth
from django.contrib.auth import logout


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login_auth(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: thanks but logout not work

Comment: def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')

Comment: error --------------RecursionError at /logout/
maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: @dadigame: you made the same mistake with `logout`... Reread the answer...